# How can i delete an element from a web-scraping data?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used Beautifulsoup and soup.findAll to reach the relevant information, but i want to delete 1 value (which is between `<TR>...</TR>`) whit his `<TR>` tag to.
How can i do this? Python 2.7

```
.
.
.

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

tab6col = soup.findAll('table', { "class" : "tab6col" })
```

Here my html code:

```html
[<table border="0" class="tab6col" id="pm">\n<tr><td>\xa0</td><td align="right" class="contentword"><b>2015. \xe9v</b></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><b>2014. \xe9v</b></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><b>2013. \xe9v</b></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><b>2012. \xe9v</b></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><b>2011. \xe9v</b></td></tr><tr><td class="contentword"><b>Besz\xe1mol\xe1si id\xf5szak</b></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><span class="pm_idoszak">2015.01.01. - 2015.12.31.</span></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><span class="pm_idoszak">2014.01.01. - 2014.12.31.</span></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><span class="pm_idoszak">2013.12.30. - 2013.12.31.</span></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><span class="pm_idoszak">Nincs adat.</span></td><td align="right" class="contentword"><span class="pm_idoszak">Nincs adat.</span></td></tr><tr><td>\xa0</td><td align="right" class="contentword">eFt</td><td align="right" class="contentword">eFt</td><td align="right" class="contentword">eFt</td><td align="right" class="contentword">eFt</td><td align="right" class="contentword">eFt</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">\xc9rt\xe9kes\xedt\xe9s nett\xf3 \xe1rbev\xe9tele</td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Bev\xe9telek</td><td align="right" class="numberc">2 873 821</td><td align="right" class="numberc">3 162 742</td><td align="right" class="numberc">9 194</td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">\xdczemi eredm\xe9ny</td><td align="right" class="numberc">81 937</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-181 850</td><td align="right" class="numberc">1 755</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Ad\xf3z\xe1s el\xf5tti eredm\xe9ny</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-192 778</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-169 476</td><td align="right" class="numberc">1 755</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">M\xe9rleg szerinti eredm\xe9ny</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-124 099</td><td align="right" class="numberc">0</td><td align="right" class="numberc">1 421</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Ad\xf3zott eredm\xe9ny</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-192 778</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-169 476</td><td align="right" class="numberc">1 579</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Eszk\xf6z\xf6k \xf6sszesen</td><td align="right" class="numberc">37 820 881</td><td align="right" class="numberc">40 695 842</td><td align="right" class="numberc">36 992 091</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Befektetett eszk\xf6z\xf6k</td><td align="right" class="numberc">18 668 826</td><td align="right" class="numberc">18 525 063</td><td align="right" class="numberc">16 925 711</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Forg\xf3eszk\xf6z\xf6k</td><td align="right" class="numberc">19 008 587</td><td align="right" class="numberc">21 877 275</td><td align="right" class="numberc">19 792 420</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">P\xe9nzeszk\xf6z\xf6k</td><td align="right" class="numberc">947 015</td><td align="right" class="numberc">1 056 101</td><td align="right" class="numberc">1 307 515</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Akt\xedv id\xf5beli elhat\xe1rol\xe1sok</td><td align="right" class="numberc">143 468</td><td align="right" class="numberc">293 504</td><td align="right" class="numberc">273 960</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke</td><td align="right" class="numberc">2 141 319</td><td align="right" class="numberc">2 184 079</td><td align="right" class="numberc">2 353 554</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">C\xe9ltartal\xe9kok</td><td align="right" class="numberc">29 656</td><td align="right" class="numberc">148 652</td><td align="right" class="numberc">18 960</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">K\xf6telezetts\xe9gek</td><td align="right" class="numberc">35 541 531</td><td align="right" class="numberc">38 059 399</td><td align="right" class="numberc">34 233 518</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">R\xf6vid lej\xe1rat\xfa k\xf6telezetts\xe9gek</td><td align="right" class="numberc">30 519 491</td><td align="right" class="numberc">30 426 014</td><td align="right" class="numberc">26 394 088</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Hossz\xfa lej\xe1rat\xfa k\xf6telezetts\xe9gek</td><td align="right" class="numberc">5 022 040</td><td align="right" class="numberc">7 633 385</td><td align="right" class="numberc">7 839 430</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Passz\xedv id\xf5beli elhat\xe1rol\xe1sok</td><td align="right" class="numberc">108 375</td><td align="right" class="numberc">303 712</td><td align="right" class="numberc">386 059</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword" colspan="6"><b>P\xe9nz\xfcgyi mutat\xf3k</b></td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Elad\xf3sodotts\xe1g foka <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Elad\xf3sodotts\xe1g foka&lt;/span&gt; (K\xf6telezetts\xe9gek/Eszk\xf6z\xf6k \xf6sszesen)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Megmutatja, hogy az eszk\xf6z \xe1llom\xe1ny milyen m\xe9rt\xe9kben van megterhelve k\xf6telezetts\xe9gv\xe1llal\xe1ssal. Min\xe9l kisebb a mutat\xf3 \xe9rt\xe9ke, ann\xe1l jobb a c\xe9g meg\xedt\xe9l\xe9se.&lt;/i&gt;');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Elad\xf3sodotts\xe1g m\xe9rt\xe9ke - Bonit\xe1s <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Elad\xf3sodotts\xe1g m\xe9rt\xe9ke - Bonit\xe1s&lt;/span&gt; (K\xf6telezetts\xe9gek/Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Azt mutatja, hogy a saj\xe1t forr\xe1sok a k\xf6telezetts\xe9gek h\xe1ny sz\xe1zal\xe9k\xe1t fedezik. Pozit\xedv a c\xe9g meg\xedt\xe9l\xe9se, ha a mutat\xf3 \xe9rt\xe9ke tart\xf3san (j\xf3val) 1 alatt van.&lt;/i&gt;');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">\xc1rbev\xe9tel ar\xe1nyos eredm\xe9ny % <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;\xc1rbev\xe9tel ar\xe1nyos eredm\xe9ny %&lt;/span&gt; (Ad\xf3zott eredm\xe9ny/ Nett\xf3 \xe1rbev\xe9tel)\xd7100&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;A mutat\xf3 az \xe1rbev\xe9tel hat\xe9konys\xe1g\xe1t fejezi ki \xfagy, hogy az \xe1rbev\xe9tel nyeres\xe9gtartalm\xe1t sz\xe1zal\xe9kban szeml\xe9lteti. A c\xe9g meg\xedt\xe9l\xe9se ann\xe1l pozit\xedvabb, min\xe9l magasabb a sz\xe1zal\xe9k.&lt;/i&gt;');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Likvidit\xe1si gyorsr\xe1ta <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Likvidit\xe1si gyorsr\xe1ta&lt;/span&gt; ((Forg\xf3eszk\xf6z\xf6k-K\xe9szletek)/R\xf6vid lej.k\xf6telezetts\xe9gek)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Azt fejezi ki, hogy az egy \xe9v alatt p\xe9nzz\xe9 tehet\xf5 k\xe9szletek n\xe9lk\xfcli forg\xf3eszk\xf6z\xf6k milyen ar\xe1nyban k\xe9pesek az egy \xe9ven bel\xfcl esed\xe9kes k\xf6telezetts\xe9gek fedez\xe9s\xe9re, azaz milyen a c\xe9g r\xf6vid t\xe1v\xfa fizet\xf5k\xe9pess\xe9ge.&lt;br&gt;A c\xe9g meg\xedt\xe9l\xe9se akkor pozit\xedv, ha ez az ar\xe1ny egyre n\xf6vekv\xf5, ami az azonnali fizet\xf5k\xe9pess\xe9g javul\xe1s\xe1t jelzi.&lt;/i&gt;');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td><td align="right" class="numberc">Nincs adat.</td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke ar\xe1nya <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke ar\xe1nya &lt;/span&gt; (Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke / Forr\xe1sok)');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc">0,06</td><td align="right" class="numberc">0,05</td><td align="right" class="numberc">0,06</td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Eszk\xf6zar\xe1nyos nyeres\xe9g <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Eszk\xf6zar\xe1nyos nyeres\xe9g &lt;/span&gt; (Ad\xf3zott eredm\xe9ny / Eszk\xf6z\xf6k)');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc">-0,01</td><td align="right" class="numberc">0,00</td><td align="right" class="numberc">0,00</td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Bev\xe9telar\xe1nyos eredm\xe9ny <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Bev\xe9telar\xe1nyos eredm\xe9ny &lt;/span&gt; (Ad\xf3zott eredm\xe9ny / Bev\xe9telek)');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc">-0,07</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-0,05</td><td align="right" class="numberc">0,17</td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td></tr><tr><td class="contentword">Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke ar\xe1nyos nyeres\xe9g <span onmouseout="remove_hint();" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke ar\xe1nyos nyeres\xe9g &lt;/span&gt; (Ad\xf3zott eredm\xe9ny / Saj\xe1t t\xf5ke)');" style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;">i</span></td><td align="right" class="numberc">-0,09</td><td align="right" class="numberc">-0,08</td><td align="right" class="numberc">0,00</td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td><td align="right" class="numberc"></td></tr><tr><td class="contentword" colspan="6"><b>L\xe9tsz\xe1m:</b> \xa0 136 f\xf5</td>\n</tr></table>]
```

And i want to delete this value in this table:

```html
<tr><td class="contentword" colspan="6"><b>P\xe9nz\xfcgyi mutat\xf3k</b></td></tr>
```

My full code:

```js
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

f = open('opten2.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

tab6col = soup.find('table', { "class" : "tab6col" })


datatable=[]
for record in tab6col.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))

td = datatable.find("td", text="P\xe9nz\xfcgyi mutat\xf3k")
td.decompose()


maindatatable = to_2d(datatable, 6)
print maindatatable
output.writerows(maindatatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, what would you like to delete, exactly? The tables?

Comment: show sample example or say input and desired output

Comment: I used bsoup to get a table, and i want to delete a value between this TR.
I update my question, and insert the full html code, its easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose). Find the `td` tag and use `deompose()` to delete it.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml")
tab6col = soup.find("table", { "class" : "tab6col" })
td = tab6col.find("tr", text="P\xe9nz\xfcgyi mutat\xf3k")
td.decompose()
```

**EDIT**

Try this.

```
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

f = open('opten2.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()
f.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml') 
tab6col = soup.find('table', { "class" : "tab6col" }) 

datatable=[]
for record in tab6col.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
    datatable.append(temp_data)

output.writerows(datatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: So i have to use it?

` td = tab6col.find("<tr><td class="contentword" colspan="6"><b>P\xe9nz\xfcgyi mutat\xf3k</b></td></tr>", align=False)
td.decompose()`

Comment: @tardos93 Nope. Not in that way. Do you want to delete all the `td` tags which have no align attribute ??

Comment: Of course not. I want delete only this data with his td tags too.

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Ahh, i am totally lost. It isnt work, + i want to delete with the <TR> tag too.
Can you check this what i have to change? http://kepkezelo.com/images/qd9xm0lpxgpou7o14qcg.png

Comment: @tardos93 Is my current code not working ? I have tested locally using your code snippet, it worked perfectly. Just change the `td` to `tr` in the find method. I have updated my code, check it.

Comment: I update my question and put there my code. Can you correct in that, because i dont know sure where i have to use this part of your code.

Comment: @tardos93 You have used `decompose` after the `record` loop, use it before the loop.

Comment: I modified it, i get this error :
"File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147350/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-tardos93).